# convert list of strings to list of widgets in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have simple method like this:

```dart
List<Widget> stringsToWidgets( List<String>? a) {
    List<Text> b = [];
    for (var item in a) {
      b.add(Text(item));
    }
    return b;
  }
  Column(children: stringsToWidgets(["1", "2", "3"]));
```

I have column, and children of it come from this method.
How to do it faster in place, without this `stringsToWidgets` method?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I found solution:

```dart
Column(
   children:
   for ( var i in ["1", "2", "3"] ) 
      Text(i)
);
```

Comment: `i` is already a string, why do you have to add the `.toString()`?

Comment: You're right, I just test previously version of code where I had  `List<String?>?` instead of `List<String>? a`